# Visual C++ 2012 Runtime Library prerequisite for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010 Professional, and I was wondering if there's any way to add the **Visual C++ 2012 Runtime Library**, to the Prerequisites of a Setup Project?

At the moment I only have the option to choose the **Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Library**

I already tried the link (present on the prerequisites configuration screen) entitled **Check Microsoft Update for more redistributable components** but I get redirected to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa496123.aspx and can't find anything to add that functionality do Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: VS2010 doesn't have the time machine to guess what VS2012 was going to look like.  Just add the individual files and have them copied into the app's install directory.  You'll need msvcr120.dll, possibly msvcp120.dll.  Do keep in mind that having multiple versions of the CRT in one program is very unhealthy.

Comment: I know that about the "time machine" but since that is just a "information tag" to the exe, I was wondering if there was any way to add that prerequisites. And the Microsoft link at the prerequisites configuration screen also seem to indicate that that possibility exists.

Comment: You need a "bootstrapper" to get the Setup wizard to offer the prerequisite.  Bootstrapper\Packages subdirectory in the Windows SDK directory stores them.  How much trouble you'll get into when you copy them is fairly unguessable, you'd have to try.  Don't overwrite any.

Comment: I had just found that out :)
Currently following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee726596.aspx to see how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a **vcredist_x86 (2012)** folder in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages** with following structure:

```
+ vcredist_x86 (2012)
|     + en
|     |_  package.xml
|_  product.xml
|_  vcredist_x86.exe
```

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
  Name="DisplayName"
  Culture="Culture"
>
    <Strings>
        <String Name="DisplayName">Visual C++ 2012 Runtime Libraries (x86)</String>
        <String Name="Culture">en</String>
        <String Name="AdminRequired">You do not have the permissions required to install Visual C++ 2012 Runtime Libraries (x86). Please contact your administrator.</String>
        <String Name="InvalidPlatformWin9x">Installation of Visual C++ 2012 Runtime Libraries (x86) is not supported on Windows 95. Contact your application vendor.</String>
        <String Name="InvalidPlatformWinNT">Installation of Visual C++ 2012 Runtime Libraries (x86) is not supported on Windows NT 4.0. Contact your application vendor.</String>
        <String Name="GeneralFailure">A failure occurred attempting to install Visual C++ 2012 Runtime Libraries (x86).</String>
    </Strings>
</Package>
```

**product.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Product
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
  ProductCode="Microsoft.Visual.C++.12.0.x86"
>
  <PackageFiles>
    <PackageFile Name="vcredist_x86.exe" HomeSite="VCRedistExe"/>
  </PackageFiles>

  <InstallChecks>
    <MsiProductCheck Property="VCRedistInstalled" Product="{DA5E371C-6333-3D8A-93A4-6FD5B20BCC6E}"/>
  </InstallChecks>

  <Commands Reboot="Defer">
    <Command PackageFile="vcredist_x86.exe" 
         Arguments=' /q:a ' 
         >

      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="VCRedistInstalled" Compare="ValueGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="3"/>
        <!-- Block install if user does not have admin privileges -->
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
      </InstallConditions>

      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>

    </Command>
  </Commands>
</Product>
```

Comment: Is product.xml correct? The ProductCode is for C++ v12, whereas I'm guessing the question was for C++ v11 (used with Visual Studio 2012).  And the Product is set to the package code for "Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)", if this link (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/3494/how-to-detect-the-presence-of-the-visual-cpp-2010-redist-pac.aspx) is correct.